# Checking whether an expression is `constexpr`

Tags: c++, c++11

C++17 adds constexpr if  ( to choose if to compile a statement if the condition is a constexpr ) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Is there a trick to emulate a limited form of this construct in C++11 ?

If would need the following construct in a macro:

```
  #define ALLOCATE(x) if ({x is a constant}) allocate_n<x>() else allocate(x)
```

Comment: that's not what `if constexpr` does...

Comment: It took you less time to write that than for me to edit the question. wow.

Comment: @MichaelMoser there's a small number of toxic users, and a large number of helpful ones  , unfortunately we have no way of "voting people off the island" so to speak

Comment: Yeah, that's quite a harsh reception for a simple misunderstanding. However, Brian is right: `if constexpr` (despite the name) does not check whether the condition is `constexpr`, it *requires* it to be and conditionally compiles its branches. Passing in a non-`constexpr` expression is a hard error. I'll let you reword your question :)

Answer (score 4):

Supposing that you're using GCC or Clang, you can use the [`__builtin_constant_p()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fconstant_005fp-4210) extension:

```
#define ALLOCATE(x) \
    __builtin_constant_p(x) \
        ? allocate_n<__builtin_constant_p(x) ? x : 0>() \
        : allocate(x)
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d98bb6a999e1af6c)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a trick to emulate a limited form of this construct in C++11 ?

The best I can imagine is substitute

```
if constexpr ( cond ) statment-1 else statement-2;
```

with

```
foo<cond>( /* ? */ );
```

where `foo()` is defined as follows

```
template <bool>
void foo (/* ? */);

template <>
void foo<true> (/* ? */)
 { /* statement-1 */ }

template <>
void foo<false> (/* ? */)
 { /* statement-2 */ }
```